# Determination of a script piping an output into another script

Tags: bash, pipe, stdin, file-descriptor

I have 2 scripts. Script a.sh is piping output to script b.sh processing the output as follows:

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo output | ./b.sh  ### piping into STDIN of b.sh script
$
$ cat b.sh
#!/bin/bash
grep output ### reading from STDIN
$
$ ./a.sh
output
```

Is there any way I can determine in script b.sh from which script it's getting input? I would like b.sh script to find out it's a.sh. I tried to work with content of /proc/$$/fd in combination with lsof but without success.

Comment: Why do you want to know? What are you going to do differently? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: each script should be a different process, you should be able to figure it out from a ps command from the b.sh script :) the parent process should be the a.sh script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a silly solution but you can use ps to find the parent process than get the command from that process again using ps.

Example by by adding this to the b.sh you gave above:

```
ps -p $(ps -o ppid= -p $$) -o cmd=
```

the output when called from the a.sh script was:

```
/bin/bash ./a.sh
```

when called directly from the command line:

```
-bash
```

I suppose you could do it using the /proc/$$ folders to achieve the same thing looking in /proc/$$ get the parentPid and read /proc/$(parentPid)/cmdline to get the same result.

so this way you would do something like:

```
parentPid=$(cat /proc/$$/stat | awk '{print $4}')
cat /proc/$(parentPid)/cmdline
```

output when b.sh is called from a.sh:

```
/bin/bash./a.sh
```

Comment: I was able to do so by running: cat /proc/$PPID/cmdline | strings | tail -n +2

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ps` command with the `PPID` option, or the `caller` command to check which script called it.